# Truncate output to exactly one page

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use `less` to grab exactly the first page of output from a command. I expected `foo | less -X +q` to display the first page of output and then quit but it display nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo | less -X +rq` (or `+Rq`) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `head` instead.

```
foo | head -n "$LINES"
```

Comment: `head` doesn't automagically deal with line wrapping in the same friendly way that `less` does